# Stripping text from url

Tags: php, strip

Im trying to strip find_loc= and &cflt=pizza  I got the majority stripped its just these last 2 things and whenever I try to use trim it doesn't delete it out it keeps saying array even when i try to print it, it says array.

```
<?php
    $foo = 'http://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=2190+W+Washington+Blvd%2C+Los+Angeles+90018&cflt=pizza ';

    $blah = parse_url($foo);

    $blah[query];

//the code above echos out find_loc=2190+W+Washington+Blvd%2C+Los+Angeles+90018&cflt=pizza

    $thids = trim(''.$blah.'','find_loc=');

    echo $thids;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$thids = str_replace(array('&cflt=pizza','find_loc='), '', $blah);
```

Comment: it was actually =) $thids = str_replace(array('&cflt=pizza','find_loc='), '', $blah);

Answer (score 1):

```
parse_str($blah['query'], $query_vars); // decompose query string into components

unset($query_vars['find_loc']); // delete this particular query variable/value
unset($query_vars['cflt']);

$blah['query'] = http_build_query($query_vars); // rebuild the query string

$foo = http_build_url($blah); // rebuild the url
```

Comment: The first line should be `parse_str($blah['query'], $query_vars);` parse_str() does not return the array. You have to pass it as a second parameter.